# PHP Hex String Send as Socket

Tags: php, sockets, hex

I have the following hex format in string variable:

```
$str = "0dae28";
```

I would like to send the above as hex value (e.g. 0x0dae28) via the socket interface using:

```
socket_write($spawn,$output,strlen($output));
```

Therefore, I am curious on what should I do to go from `$str` to `$output` so that `$output` is sent as hex formatted data.

Any input is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: why not just prepend `0x` to the front ?

Comment: Do you want to send the string `'0x0dae28'`, or the binary/numeric value of `0x0dae28`?

Comment: @ManseUK I tried to do $str = "0x{$str}" and send it - it will send as a regular ASCII string. I have tried "\x{$str}" as well.

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Sorry what to try?

Comment: @deceze the binary value of 0x0dae28. How can I pass the value from $str (which is ASCII in hex code format) to a variable in hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's [`hex2bin()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) function:

> **Example #1 hex2bin() example**
>   `<?php
> $hex = hex2bin("6578616d706c65206865782064617461");
> var_dump($hex);
> ?>`
>   The above example will output something similar to:
>
> ```
> string(16) "example hex data"
> ```

Thus, in your case:

```
$output = hex2bin($str);
```

Comment: Will $output be interpreted as an ASCII or a binary? I am sorry but at the moment the server I am using is still using PHP < 5.4.0. Thus, I want to make sure what the function is returning before upgrading it. Thanks!!

Comment: @HeruS: In your case, `$output` will then contain the three bytes `0x0dae28`.  How do you mean "will it be *interpreted* as an ASCII or binary"?

Comment: thanks for the input. I will try this asap and let you know how it goes. thanks.